# PHP Parts Property

Tags: php, properties

I'm working on some code written by another developer and it is written in PHP.  There is a line of code that is causing an error.  I'm thinking that it is something you have to enable for PHP because it works just fine in another environment but doesn't work on the new environment and I haven't changed the code yet.  The line is:

```
$structure->parts
```

`$structure` is a variable I've passed in but from a search online `parts` is a property.  The error I'm getting says:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$parts

Thanks for any help or ideas anyone might have.

Comment: More code needed – it's impossible to diagnose this as is. Where does `$structure` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like parts doesn't exist there.  Try running var_dump($structure) to get a better picture of what you're really dealing with.